# RecyclerView Crashes when delete first item if 'setHasStableIds(true)' is in adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

My RecyclerView crashes if I set

```
init{
   setHasStableIds(true)
}
```

in my ListAdapter. If I remove this code it works without any issue. Logcat below

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.starsolutions.starfilemanager, PID: 10919
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:-1).state:2 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{4a24664 VFED..... ......ID 0,147-1080,1878 #7f080181 app:id/rvExplorer}, adapter:com.starsolutions.starfilemanager.ui.ExplorerAdapter@efe3a61, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@e9986, context:com.starsolutions.starfilemanager.MainActivity@a4f9b5f
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6183)
```

Comment: Are your IDs not unique? Do you even need stable IDs in the first place? How does your code for removal look like? Elaborate on your issue.

Comment: yea my ids are are unique.  for deleting an item i remove it from List myList<String> and use ListAdapter.submitList(myList) if there any changes. For every item its working except first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Id was the position of item in List.

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()
```

Now I replaced 'position.toLong()' with other unique numbers and the issue solved.

Comment: Hey can you look this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71380874/11560810)

Comment: Sorry bro I'm a beginner in Android. Can I use  a constraint layout instead of frame and relative layout?